# Return multiple PartialViews at the same time dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm in a MVC4 project.

Currently, I am returning PartialViews (containing a table with data) dynamically through jQuery.

This is the setup:

```
$('#selector').change(function () {

    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if (selectedValue == "def") {
        $('#result').text("Välj ett språk för att visa substanstabell..");
    } else if (selectedValue == "sv") {
        $('#spin').show();
        $.get('/SubstanceValidation/svSubstances/' + selectedValue, function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
            $('#spin').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    } else if (selectedValue == "en") {
        $('#spin').show();
        $.get('/SubstanceValidation/enSubstances/' + selectedValue, function (data) {

            $('#result').html(data);
            $('#spin').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    } else if (selectedValue == "fi") {
        $('#spin').show();
        $.get('/SubstanceValidation/fiSubstances/' + selectedValue, function (data) {

            $('#result').html(data);
            $('#spin').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    } else if (selectedValue == "fp") {
        $('#spin').show();
        $.get('/SubstanceValidation/fpSubstances/' + selectedValue, function (data) {

            $('#result').html(data);
            $('#spin').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    } else if (selectedValue == "ge") {
        $('#spin').show();
        $.get('/SubstanceValidation/geSubstances/' + selectedValue, function (data) {

            $('#result').html(data);
            $('#spin').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
});
```

This works fine.

Now, I would like my `<input type="button" id="getAllBtn" value="Get all" />` to return all PartialViews and render them in the result `<div>` at once. I tried the following without any success:

```
$('#getAllBtn').click(function () {
    $('#spin').show();
    $.get('/SubstanceValidation/svSubstances/' + '/SubstanceValidation/enSubstances/' + '/SubstanceValidation/fiSubstances/' + '/SubstanceValidation/fpSubstances/' + '/SubstanceValidation/geSubstances/', function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
        $('#spin').hide();
        $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why did you concat the url ? Just create a View with theses partial views server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to realize that in MVC an action method can only return ONE and ONLY ONE `ActionResult` object...for that reason you can only return one partial view at a time. Having that in mind, your only option (I think) is to create another PartialView that invokes/renders all other partial views you want to render. Then, create an action method that returns this "master" partial view

```
public ActionResult AllSubstances(){...}
```

And then invoke this action method from jQuery...

```
$('#getAllBtn').click(function () {
    $('#spin').show();
    $.get('/SubstanceValidation/AllSubstances/', function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
        $('#spin').hide();
        $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I know, this is why I have multiple `ActionResults` in my controller passing in these `PartialViews` one by one. I like your suggestion though, and this works. I will re-think and limitize the amount of `PartialViews` I currently have and prepend more logic to get the right 'content' of the view based on server-side logic instead of my dirty client side solution. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty code....

First,I suggest you to merge the ajax request part in change event,example：

```
$('#selector').change(function () {

    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if (selectedValue == "def") {
        $('#result').text("Välj ett språk för att visa substanstabell..");
    } else {
        $('#spin').show();
        $.get('/SubstanceValidation/' + selectedValue + 'Substances/' + selectedValue, function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
            $('#spin').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
});
```

Now return to your topic,you can do it by request all your urls and append return data to div like this:

```
 var allUrls=["sv","en","fi"......];
 for(var i=0;i<allUrls.length;i++){
    $.get('/SubstanceValidation/AllSubstances/', function (data) {
      $('#result').append(data);//do not use html because it will replace last request
      $('#spin').hide();
      $('#result').fadeIn('fast');
    });
 }
```

But it's not a best solution since you can't control the display order(you don't know which ajax request is faster),if the order is important,you should write a new Action to return all data just like @Leo said.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I decided to take another slight direction based on the help I got from Leo.